# By.repeater not working with a filter

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I have the following function to see if the bindings in my repeater (for example `{{car.details.year}}`) match an array of expected bindings.

```
    var ngrepeat = 'car in filteredInventory = (vm.vehicles | filter: search | orderBy:vm.sort.value)',
    expectVehicleColumns = function(binding, expectations, name) {
        element.all(By.repeater(ngrepeat).column(binding)).then(function(arr) {
            //This fails when I add a filter
            expect(arr.length, 'Number of displayed vehicles').to.eql(expectations.length);
            arr.forEach(function(wd, i) {
                wd.getText().then(function(text) {
                    console.log(text);
                    expect(text, name).to.eql(expectations[i]);
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

and then implemented a such

```
    expectVehicleTitles = function(expectedVehicleTitles) {
        var binding = '{{car.details.year}} {{car.details.make}} {{car.details.model}} {{car.details.trim}}';
        expectVehicleColumns(binding, expectedVehicleTitles, 'Vehicle Title');
    };
```

This works fine when I have no filter, it sees all the vehicle in the repeater. However, when I run that function after doing `element(By.model('filter')).sendKeys('some filter');`, the array length is 0 even though it looks fine on the browser.

Note `filter: search` because `search` is a method that uses `$scope.filter`

Comment: Nvm, it appears to be a problem with my .column binding